# set a php variable only in the iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe

so i have a code like this:

```
if ($var == null || 'NULL'){
echo "<h1>something</h1>";
echo "<div id='footer'><b>something</b><br/><br/><br/></div>";
echo "<b>something</b>";}
    else {}
```

so, on my main page the value `var == null` and that's great because i want those linse to be displayed in that page, but if i have an iframe somewhere else and i want to set this variable to 1 like `$var = 1` so it doesn't show in the iframe but instead will show on the main page because there the value is null, how can i do this?

Comment: You can't detect if your page is being shown in an `iframe` with PHP.

Comment: are you sure you want to `if ($var == null || 'NULL')`, not `if (is_null($var) || $var === 'NULL')` ?

Comment: YOu should change `if ($var == null || 'NULL'){` to `if (empty($var)){`

Comment: yes, it's not an issue that, i meant `if (empty($var)){` but my question how to trigger it from the iframe with someJquery or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't detect an iframe on the server-side, but you can pass an additional parameter to your script when embedding an `iframe` on your page:

```
<iframe src="script.php?iframe=1"></iframe>
```

And then check for the value of `$_GET['iframe']`.

Comment: But you will lose it when you navigate to another page in the iframe.